# Передача переменных из одной формы в другую

Tags: c#

Не знаю почему но возникла такая проблема: У меня есть 5 форм например.Например я делаю в 1 форме глобальные переменные. Приравниваю их к чему то. По дебагеру смотрю что они приравнялись. Вроде все ок. Но например создаю объект данной формы и пытаюсь извлечь в переменную а в дебагере показывает значение null. Ладно думаю может я что то подзабыл что то упустил. Создал отдельный класс, создал ему пару свойств и в эти свойства запихнул данные значения.Смотрю в первой форме в дебагере всё пучком. Потом пытаюсь извлечь в другой форме и опять при попытке извлечь в дебагере показывает null.Кто знает в чем проблема?

```
ClientConnect client = new ClientConnect();
            string a1;
            a1 = client.receiveFam;
            string a2;
            a2 = client.receiveName;
            string a3 = client.receiveGroup;
            a3 = client.receiveGroup;
```

Вот  примерный код получения данных.

Comment: А в C# нет глобальных переменных. Может покажете?

Comment: так у Вас https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368129/c-sharp-global-variables ?

Comment: я имел ввиду переменные которые публичные. Но да признаю не правильно написал.

Comment: Вы создаёте _новый_ экземпляр класса `ClientConnect`. Естественно, его поля/свойства пусты. Вы должны передавать ссылку на ранее созданный экземпляр туда. где хотите получить из него данные.